# Installatron auto update of Wordpress failed due to lack of space. Will it automatically retry?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I have some Wordpress sites set up through Installatron in cPanel, and their Automatic Update setting in Installatron is configured to "Update to new minor versions and security releases."

Several sites failed to install a recent update due to a lack of disk space, since a backup is automatically taken first and there wasn't room for it. I've freed up disk space now, but I don't know whether or not Installatron will automatically retry installing the updates. Will it? If so, then when?

Answer (score 1):

The [Installatron documentation](http://installatron.com/docs/websiteowner) says:

> #### Automatic Update
>
> The "Automatic Update" feature will automatically backup and update installed applications immediately as new versions become available.
>
> Updates execute between midnight and 6AM server time, the created backup is automatically restored if the update fails, and email notifications are sent with the result of each update.

It does not address whether a retry will happen or not.   It sounds like if it did, it would happen the next night during the midnight to 6AM window.   If the update didn't happen the next night, you will have to trigger the upgrade manually.

The documentation has instructions for [how to upgrade an install](http://installatron.com/docs/websiteowner#upgrade).